# Android - Good practices to avoid Memory leaks

Tags: android, performance, memory, memory-leaks, imageview

**Do you know good practices to avoid memory leaks ?**

I am currently working on an app which has few memory leaks, that I struggle to fix, mainly because I don't know the habits that I need to take to be able to avoid them.

For instance, at the moment I get this issue

```
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
Failed to allocate a 1627572 byte allocation with 1293760 free bytes and 1263KB until OOM
 Raw Text
dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray (VMRuntime.java)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:429)
com.XX.Dialog.PopupDialog.onCreateView (PopupDialog.java:50)
```

Which comes from the `inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_popup, container, false);` in the `onCreateView` !

```
Here is the DialogFragment concerned : 

public final class PopupDialog extends DialogFragment {

    public PopupDialog()
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_popup, container, false);
        return view;
    }
```

The layout is quite long, but basically it got 5 ImageViews . Here is an sample :

```
    <ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/popup_top_bg_iv"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="false"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
    android:src="@drawable/popup_top_bg"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:background="@color/transparent" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/popup_top_bg_iv"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/popup_bottom_ll" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:id="@+id/popup_top_iv"
    android:src="@drawable/popup_0_top"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp" />
```

....

**So .... I was wondering if you know :**

**1. What could lead to this memory leak error from this dialogFragment ?**

**2. Any good practices in android to avoid memory leaks ?**

For instance for that file, should I call

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(null);
```

On every Imageview when the popup is closed / Activity is closed (R.drawable.* ) ? Or just when I load an image from an URL (with Glide for instance) dynamically ?

Should I **always** resize an image to the dimension of my Imageview ? 
What exactly do I need to clean after the Fragment/Activity is closed ?

What do you think ?

Comment: That is not a memory leak error, strictly speaking. You are attempting to allocate 1627572 bytes in a block. That is probably from a drawable resource; the full stack trace in LogCat would help determine that. That block is equivalent to a 637x637-pixel image, which is fairly large. My guess is that you put something in `res/drawable/` that is designed for a higher screen density (e.g., `res/drawable-xhdpi/`). The fact that you have only 1293760 bytes of heap space left *is* a sign of memory leaks, but they may be far removed from this code.

Comment: hey @CommonsWare thanks for your responsive. The Drawable folder contains only .xml files. Most of my pngs are in the drawable-xhdpi folder already!

Comment: OK, do you have some fairly large drawable that you are referencing in that layout?

Comment: Just keep layout simple and use resources as much as you need. Use small images when you are using it in small space. Some ImageLoader libraries may help you to load image. Android developer guide to load images may help you, you can find it from official site.

Comment: Thanks @JadavLalit for your comment. I am actually using Glide to load images already.
CommonsWare, I compressed all the images, will see how it goes! :)

Answer (score 3):

After a bit of digging I came with these solutions :

- you can use **Leak canary** to track your memory leak (https://github.com/square/leakcanary)
- Or the Memory monitor of Android studio : https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/am-memory.html
- Use a library to load your images such as Picasso or Glide. Personally I prefer Glide.

https://medium.com/@multidots/glide-vs-picasso-930eed42b81d

- Never keep references of **Activity** of **context** in static. NEVER! 
  Otherwise your references might still be there even if you need it.
- Avoid keeping references of ImageViews. Recycle / Clear the bitmap inside when your destroy the view.
- If you need to have a reference of the context, please use `context.getApplicationContext();`
- Don't use `context.getApplicationContext();` for `LayoutInflater.from(context);` but directly the context.

(in case if you need to inflate a view or need a context for something).
If you use the context.getApplicationContext() it can lead to some design issues if you create views dynamically.

- If you get some **OutOfMemory error**, think to compress your images ! It actually saves me lot of OutOfMemory error. You can use https://tinypng.com/.
- Don't put by default your images into the folder **drawable-xhdpi** but **drawable-mdpi** instead as **drawable-mdpi** is the default one.

So for my issue I just need to **compress the images** and put them back in the **drawable-mdpi** folder ! All good now !